# Python Error: truth value of Series is ambigious in if-statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I have a problem concerning comparing the values of two dataframes on a per day basis.
The dataframes contain df1 = minimum temperature values per day and df2 = maximum temperature values per day.

The dfs look like this (TS_TIMESTAMP is the index column):

df1:

```
> TS_TIMESTAMP              Date        TREND_VALUE             
> 2019-04-03 18:48:10.970  2019-04-02   8.340000        
> 2019-04-04 16:49:23.320  2019-04-03   7.840000           
> 2019-04-05 13:19:33.550  2019-04-04   7.480000
```

df2:

```
> TS_TIMESTAMP              Date        TREND_VALUE             
> 2019-04-03 18:48:10.970  2019-04-02   19.340000        
> 2019-04-04 16:49:23.320  2019-04-03   18.840000          
> 2019-04-05 13:19:33.550  2019-04-04   18.480000
```

I would like to calculate the difference between max_value and min_value per day with a function (to simply run the calculation with a number of different files).

This is what I came up with:

```
def temp_diff (df1, df2):
    for row in df1, df2:
        if df1.Date == df2.Date:
            print (df2.TREND_VALUE - df1.TREND_VALUE)
```

if I run this function I get this Error Message for the if-statement: 
**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

I'm not sure how to change my def appropriately.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using an all condition, this will print when ***all*** the values in df1['Date'] and df2['Date'] are equal. If that's what you want here you go:

```
def temp_diff (df1, df2):
    for row in df1, df2:
        if (df1.Date == df2.Date).all():
            print (df1.TREND_VALUE - df2.TREND_VALUE)
```

I have a feeling you want to iterate over each row and chceck whether there's a match for `df1['Date']` and `df2['Date']` so that if there is, print the difference, otherwise skip that row. Let me know in the comments if that's what you want, then I'll edit this answer.

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'Date':['2019-04-02','2019-04-03','2019-04-04'],'Values':[8,7,4]}
b = {'Date':['2019-04-02','2019-04-03','2019-04-04'],'Values':[19,18,17]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

def temp_diff (df1, df2):
    for row in df1, df2:
        if (df1.Date == df2.Date).all():
            print (df1.Values - df2.Values)

temp_diff(df_1,df_2)
```

Output:

```
0   -11
1   -11
2   -13
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

### Edit

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {'Date':['2019-04-02','2019-04-03','2019-04-04'],'TREND_VALUE':[8,7,4]}
b = {'Date':['2019-04-02','2019-04-03','2019-04-05'],'TREND_VALUE':[19,18,17]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
df1['T_Amplitude'] = np.where((df1['Date'] == df2['Date']),df1['TREND_VALUE']-df2['TREND_VALUE'],np.nan)
print(df_1)
```

Output:

```
         Date  TREND_VALUE  T_Amplitude
0  2019-04-02            8        -11.0
1  2019-04-03            7        -11.0
2  2019-04-04            4          NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code samples are very useful! I'm going for your first option!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of rows in the dataframe is the same, you simply subtract the two columns:

```
df1.TREND_VALUE - df2.TREND_VALUE
```